# Why am I missing a return statement with else

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return

I'm trying to understand why my compiler is complaining that I'm missing a return statement, when in fact I have fail-safe else at the end of my method. Why is this the case? *When would the else not cover a return*?

Here's a primitive example:

```
public boolean greaterOrEqual(int a){
    int z = 10;
    if(z > a){
       return false;
    }
    else if(z < a){
       return true;
    }
    else{
       return true; //if if and else if fail, else is the last resort
    }
}
```

Functionally, it would be the same as this

```
public boolean greaterOrEqual(int a){
    int z = 10;
    if(z > a){
       return false;
    }
    else if(z < a){
       return true;
    }

return true; //if if and else if fail, returns true

}
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine.  Either there's a typo in your actual code when you compile, or the error is on some other line, or something else is going wrong in your environment.

Comment: You don't need any of the else's, I know it doesn't answer your question, but they are totally unnecessary.

Comment: @TofuBeer You're right, of course, but as a style matter I think it's a little better to have them there, depending on the entire code.

Comment: From a style point of view I prefer a single return per method, with the exception of early returns via parameter checking at the start of the method, usually done via throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will solve your problem:

```
public boolean greaterOrEqual(int a){
    int z = 10;
    return z <= a;
}
```

and by the way, there are many interesting articles on StackOverflow help center. I would recommend [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

The problem you have described cannot be reproduced. Each of us can compile it.

Comment: You're right, this seems to be an IDE-exclusive issue, eclipse did not hand me an error, while bluej did.

The example was a bit poor, and yes it could be simplified to what you have, but I was specifically looking at the else{} statement at the end, not how elegant the code was.

Comment: If your teacher don't force you to use BlueJ, don't. Switch to Eclipse or IntellJ as being used to one of them will speedup your work in the future.

Comment: BlueJ is required, and eclipse for some reason is buggy on my computer (strange errors that don't occur in bluej). I couldn't set up IntelliJ, although seems to be the best out of the three - I couldn't find any tutorials from JetBrains as to how to get it running.

Probably because I'm a rookie and I don't understand 70% of it's fancy features

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a result variable you can avoid the return statement inside the `if else` block.
This method has a logical structure similar to yours and probably bluej will not complain about it.

```
public boolean greaterOrEqual(int a)
{
    int z = 10;
    boolean result;
    if (a >= z)
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Although the xenteros solution is still far more elegant.